# Exact sequence of Weyl groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

If we note $A_{k}$ the category of affine algebraic groups defined over $k$ and $\mathcal{G}$ the category of finite groups, we have a functor $W:A_{k}\longrightarrow \mathcal{G}$, where $W(G)$ is the Weyl group of an algebraic group $G$. Is that functor exact?

Comment: The formulation is incomplete:  Is the field arbitrary, and how does it affect the question if it isn't algebraically closed?   Are your affine algebraic groups required to be connected, or not (and does it matter)?   In any case, what precisely do you mean by "the Weyl group" of the given group?   And by "exact" do you mean left or right or both?    The question needs more context as well.   (Why is it interesting one way or the other?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is exact on the category of *connected reductive* groups and *normal* homomorphisms over an algebraically closed field $k$.

For an algebraically closed field $k$ and a connected reductive $k$-group $G$, one can construct a canonical *based root datum ${\rm BRD}\ G$*, so we obtain a canonically defined Weyl group $W(G)=W({\rm BRD}\ G)$.

Concerning based root data, see Sections 1 and 2 in T.A  Springer, Reductive groups, in: "Automorphic forms, representations and L-functions", Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. 33, part 1, pp. 3-27, Providence 1979. See also Section 1.3 in Brian Conrad, Reductive group schemes, in: "Autour des schémas en groupes", Vol. I, pp. 93–444, Panor. Synthèses, 42/43, Soc. Math. France, Paris, 2014.

I would say  that $G\mapsto W(G)$ is *not* a functor on the category of connected reductive $k$-groups and homomorphisms of $k$-groups (how can one define  the induced homomorphism of Weyl groups?). However, it is certainly a functor on the category of connected reductive $k$-groups and *normal* homomorphisms of $k$-groups. A homomorphism of connected reductive $k$-groups is called normal if its image is a normal subgroup. To a normal homomorphism $\phi\colon G_1\to G_2$ one can associate an induced morphism of based root data
$$ \phi_{\rm BRD}\colon\, {\rm BRD}\ G_1\to{\rm BRD}\ G_2$$
and an induced homomorphism of Weyl groups
$$\phi_W\colon\, W({\rm BRD}\ G_1) \to  W({\rm BRD}\ G_2).$$

If we have a short exact sequence of connected reductive $k$-groups
     $$1\to G_1\to G_2\to G_3\to 1,$$
then we obtain an induced short exact sequence of semisimple $k$-groups of adjoint type, which clearly splits, so we obtain a split short exact sequence of Weyl groups. In other words, we obtain a short exact sequence 
  $$1\to W(G_1)\to W(G_2)\to W(G_3)\to 1,$$
where  $W(G_2)=W(G_1)\times W(G_3)$.